# How to scatter a smaller array in to a larger array using a list as index?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, sage

I need help to obtain the following type of result in Python (that I was used to in Matlab):

```
M = numpy.zeros((5,5))
m = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
indx = [0, 2, 3]

# in Matlab: M(indx,indx) = M(indx,indx) + m
```

so that the output is:

```
[[ 1.  0.  2.  3.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  0.  5.  6.  0.]
 [ 7.  0.  8.  9.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: `M[numpy.ix_(indx, indx)]=m` also works with in-place operations like `M[numpy.ix_(indx, indx)]+=m`

Comment: Thanks, Paul Panzer that solved my problem.

Comment: If @PaulPanzer posts this as an answer, then it could be accepted and other visitors would see it was answered!